# Limit Inferior of Sequence $x_n = 2^n$

Tags: limits

> I am doing a problem which said that the limit inferior of sequence $x_n = 2^n$ does not exist. But isn't that the limit inferior of this sequence is $2$, or there are different definitions of limit inferior? Thanks!

Comment: The $\liminf$ is the smallest value that some subsequence converges to. Here there is no convergent subsequence, so there is no $\liminf$ (if you allow for $+\infty$ then the $\liminf$ is $+\infty$ since every subsequence goes to $+\infty$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The limit inferior is defined as follows

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \inf x_n := \lim_{n \to \infty }\big(\inf_{m\ge n  }\hspace{4pt}  x_m\big)$$

here the limit inferior is divergent thus does not exit.

Answer (score 1):

$\beta_m=\inf\{x_n:n\ge m\}$. $\{\beta_m\}=\{2^1,2^2,...\}.$ We can easily prove that $\beta_m$ is divergent. Hence, Limit inferior doesn't exist.